# How to fix this type in TypeScript 5.4?

Tags: typescript

Typescript's 5.4.x version [introduces](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4-beta/#lib-d-ts-changes) some breaking changes in the way intersections are handled. Everything worked perfectly fine on 5.3.3.

Check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78148685/3) revision if you want to see the "original" post (after formatting edits).

Newest version is the simplified minimum reproducible example as per the comments ([TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2&ssl=1&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=21#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgZ2AIQgQQE4YIYgDwAqUEAHsBAHYAmCU2FIA2gLoB8UAvFAQFCiRQAEgFthhYmUo06DFuy5FS5arQpxhAIwgYWUAPw8oR2IhTosuPAG8ojAJJQAlhSgBrCCAD2AM27MAXFAAjFAAvuyBFBAAbtpAA) by JCalz - thanks):

```js
type MustBeArray<T extends any[]> = T
type Hmm<T extends any[]> = T extends number[] ?
    MustBeArray<{ [I in keyof T]: 1 }> : never
```

This produces an error:

```
Type '{ [I in keyof T]: 1; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'any[]'.
  Types of property 'toString' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
```

I am not sure how to proceede?

Comment: Whilst I do appreciate the fast edits and better structure, I do have to ask what was wrong with the previous title? If anything it was more informative as to what the content is? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: (See prev comment) [This version](https://tsplay.dev/NnoZVm) looks like more of a [mre] than yours. While you're fixing the image issue, you might want to use this version instead.

Comment: (See prev comments) I opened [ms/TS#57744](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57744) and can write an answer here once it's triaged. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the post and removed the image. Though I do feel like this reduces the readability of the post, it is now compliant I guess.

Comment: Presumably it reduces readability for you, but others have different size screens or fonts or screen readers, and allowing the browser to format it as text is a much better experience for a wider range of people.  You could include the screenshot *in addition to* the plain text, but having the plain text is important for all the reasons listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was introduced by [microsoft/TypeScript#57122](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57122) and released with TypeScript 5.4.  I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#57744](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57744). It's considered a regression (so essentially a bug) and it has been fixed in [microsoft/TypeScript#57801](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/57801), which should be released with TypeScript 5.5.

In the meantime, the suggested workaround from that issue is to refactor to an inner utility type that doesn't have the `any[]` requirement:

```
type _Hmm<T> = T extends number[] ? 
  MustBeArray<{ [I in keyof T]: 1 }> : never // okay

type Hmm<T extends any[]> = _Hmm<T> // okay

type Z = Hmm<[2, 3, 4]>
//   ^? type Z = [1, 1, 1]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgZ2AIQgQQE4YIYgDwAqUEAHsBAHYAmCU2FIA2gLoB8UAvFAQFCiRQA+gAkAtqMLsuRUuWq0KcUQCMIGFlAD8sRCnRZceAN5RGASSgBLClADWEEAHsAZt2YAuKAEYoAX3aeFBAAbmp84NBiEjJklDR0DCxSQlGSPOECAFqcUKmMAEwANFAAzMUALGw8APTVUPUAeppAA)

Comment: FYI [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9aG8N) is how I'd deal with your original version, using indirection to relax and impose constraints where needed.

Comment: You man, are a legend. Thanks a ton. I will try it tomorrow and report back, but judging from that palyground, it should work

Comment: They've merged the fix and it is working as it was again now, thanks for providing a workable solution in the meanwhile, you a champ!

Comment: Sadly this fix did not resolve all the issues that emerged from that same version upgrade, if / when you get the time, take a look at [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206272/another-ts-5-4-regression-i-think-how-to-go-about-fixing-this-type-in-5-4) I've made with a similar problem.