# Another TS 5.4 regression (i think).... how to go about fixing this type in 5.4

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Recent Typescript changes (5.4.x, everything worked in 5.3.3) have made some regressions which caused a number of issues. The first one I posted about **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148685/how-to-fix-this-type-in-typescript-5-4)**.

**The fix proposed in that other post does not work here, or at least I couldn't implement.**

This post eventually resulted in a fix after the community (thanks JCalz) made an issue on the TS repo itself. At the time, to me, this seemed to be related/same so I have not posted about it, instead waiting for a fix. Having tested with the newest version (the one that had a fix) and it is till broken, thus I am posting this as a separate issue.

I am not well versed enough in the magic of typescript to be confident that this is in fact an issue on their end, versus just some mess in my code, but I am pretty certain that is the case, seeing as this code worked like a charm, and think this is another regression.

**[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhGB7AkgO2BATgZwgGNgBLVTAHhiggA8dMATfKAQ0xAG0BdAPigBeKAG8AUFElQu6KKUxQA1hBCoAZrB4AuKAAo6OmDJ4BKIQIBuqUkzEBfLpjgBbAEZ4etBhGat9O+TU8KABVM0FLa1spKAB+UIkpHUwICzwxMVBIKABRBlw2EgBlCGQSVFwABVxUSFxQADk2ZwhqAWEaekYWKAADQjLgABIRQOCmlrtexMl4kMwiNjBSYDZEUgAvVomIPhmoZNT0zPBoEsGKgGkVfABhVERB8ipO7192Tl52pRV1WARkGgsDgCMQyBRKOIYjI5AplKoNDBtLBjFwAMw8ex7E7Zc5gioANTWcAgdweTwhr26rA43H4QlE+y4l1hUDx5Vw1xAZMeYOebXYrDywAKxVK+KqNTqjWarUufGR8CQKAw2DwhBI-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-XNySI-8KN07VmVZPbuS6w62mREqxQuOsKpPeVTWOhjJHa2Krvmtp9kxMRL0wa9pHhYKoyWMKfyomKk1JBTYCWlauCZHt6GaZUeyopxHixuAccZd6oFvEgADFUFQHRr1weRhze97ieAAAhdDkhcdxcDpyQ7ExfhgwyMQgA) to the TS playground**.

When attempting to use keys of a TupleIntersection inside a mapped object that would "extract" for the lack of the better word, a part of that key, the results can no longer be used to index the object that has those same keys

I would love go give a shorter example, that is not as convoluted as this, but I am not sure what else to truncate. The `ExtractSelectorPropertyName` must remain, as it does the key string converstion.

```js
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
    [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void
}[number] extends (x: infer U) => void
    ? U
    : never

type ExtractSelectorPropertyName<T> = T extends `select${infer Name}`
    ? Uncapitalize<Name>
    : never

type SelectorKeysCollection<T extends any[]> = keyof TupleToIntersection<{
    [I in keyof T]: T[I][3]
}>

type SelectorValuesCollection<T extends any[]> = {
    [K in SelectorKeysCollection<T> as ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K>]: TupleToIntersection<{ [I in keyof T]: T[I][3] }>[K]
}

function createEnhancer<T extends any[]>() {
    function mapSelectorToValueNames<K extends SelectorKeysCollection<T>>(name: K): ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K> {
        return 'lets forget the implementation detail' as ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K>
    }

    const select = <Keys extends Array<SelectorKeysCollection<T>>>(...names: Keys) => {
        names.reduce<Partial<SelectorValuesCollection<T>>>((acc, name) => {

            // ISSUE HERE:
            acc[mapSelectorToValueNames(name)] = 'whatever' as any
            return acc
        }, {})
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

> Type 'ExtractSelectorPropertyName<keyof TupleToIntersection<{ [I in keyof T]: T[I][3]; }>>' cannot be used to index type 'Partial<SelectorValuesCollection>'.(2536)

**EDIT:** Remedied the code to have a bit better example where only types are included and implementation detail is removed.

POST-EDIT:
It is my understanding that TSC does not see these two types as equal, though it used to do just fine before, and what is more, the example (also included in the TSplayground link) showcases that they are indeed same:

```js
// =====================================
// by inspecting the keys, mappedKeys and values
// we can see that the ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K>
// indeed fits the `SelectorValuesCollection<T>` indexes
// =====================================

declare function TEST<T extends any[]>():
    [
        SelectorKeysCollection<T>,
        { [K in SelectorKeysCollection<T>]: ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K> },
        SelectorValuesCollection<T>
    ]

const [keys, mappedKeys, values] = TEST<[
    ['example', null, null, {
        selectFoo: string,
        selectBar: number,
    }]
]>()
```

Comment: "I would love to give a shorter example, that is not as convoluted as this, but I am not sure what else to truncate." 

Comment: I really do not know what I could remove to make it more apparent :( Okay let me try to remove all the actual CODE and leave this on types only... but i dont know if i can ever get types to be less

Comment: With the code as written I would be inclined to just use the following crowbar somewhere to fix it, [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mpoJgN) (if you know `X` is assignable to `Y` but the compiler doesn't, then `X & Y` can often be used in place of `X`).  There might be something "nicer", and I don't know what to say about TS5.3 vs TS5.4.  But that should at least get you moving forward? I can't commit to look at this further right now, though.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the time you can expand, I will look into this as a solution until i can find a way to present this issue in a better way so that you can more easily approach it

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your crowbar solution, it works, so that is enough to move the codebase forward, I have, in the meantime updated the post and have removed the fluff / provided examples. That said, I feel like this is a regression in TS itself, but am unsure how to proceed with it... I do not understand what is happening, but the types shown in the example should match... I do not know where or why TS5.4 is losing this

Comment: Well it looks like one of the PRs committed around 2023-11-30 did it, but I'm not going to be able to spend time bisecting it for you right now. Maybe you want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/every-ts#bisecting and figure it out yourself?

Comment: And it looks like it's already fixed in TS5.5 nightly

Comment: All right I ran the bisect: broken by https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55140 and fixed in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55371. Neither of those have much to do with each other, so I'd say that the typing you're doing here is past what is really intended to be easily supported by TS, since it hinges upon little vagaries of implementation. I can write up an answer if you want, but I don't know if it's useful to future readers. Thoughts?

Comment: I would appriciate your anwer as they are very often riddled with references, such as in these comments and make it a good "research topic" so that people (myselfincluded) can learn. If you have suggestions on how to amend these types (other than the crowbar solution) that would be a suitiable approach - seeing as how the current implementation hinges on little implementation details in ts, that would also be appriciated but i feel might be beyond the scope of this issue. Thanks for all the help, you are a lifesaver as always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to say exactly why your code worked before, stopped working, and then apparently works again in the nightly version of TypeScript. I mean, it's relatively straightforward to give a rundown of the "what" but not the "how":

- Your code broke with [microsoft/TypeScript#55140](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55140), a bug fix for [microsoft/TypeScript#55129](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55129), an issue with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). This was  released with TypeScript 5.4.
- Your code was fixed with [microsoft/TypeScript#55371](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/55371), a bug fix for [microsoft/TypeScript#55364](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55364), an issue with [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types). This will be released with TypeScript 5.5.

These issues don't have anything obvious to do with each other. Your code does involve mapped types and template literal types, so it's quite possible that the break and the fix are touching different pieces of your code and it's essentially a coincidence.

If you *need* to know what's going on you might try to come up with a more minimal example, and/or file your own GitHub issue about it.  Until and unless that happens I don't have any further insight.

---

On the other hand, a general approach for situations in which you are sure that a type `X` is assignable to a type `Y` but the compiler can't see it (generally because one or both types depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types, and the compiler doesn't have much ability to do higher-order generic reasoning), you can often use the [intersection(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `X & Y` instead of `X`. If you're correct about the assignability, then ultimately `X & Y` will be equivalent (more or less) to `X`. And the compiler will always recognize `X & Y` is assignable to `X`, by definition of the intersection.

So, in your example, you could always do something like

```
declare function createEnahncer<T extends any[]>(composition: T) {
  const mapSelectorToValueNames = <K extends SelectorKeysCollection<T>>(
      name: K
  ): (keyof SelectorValuesCollection<T>) & ExtractSelectorPropertyName<K>;
```

to avoid the error.  If you're using complicated types (especially things like `UnionToIntersection`) then you will probably eventually need something like this, even if the particular issue in your question turns out to be a real bug.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#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-10WcIBMAA6D1gF-XQjQGMEuDZJ8AC0eEQgBqI0TBMYCYhDO0al9XJOQqXRehGKDcBguCdRMOwoGdUkoEwVBgxQ38oEwgVeOaGCoDAT0QUwRDejI8jzUta09GY1j4KQ-B1iICBdAANgAGigAB2JDQwAGVQf1cFuBVdLMQjyL5aDMFgjTEK00gdN0UyzAVcMAG59jsDIYhrOsRODLshVYXt3g5LlKHXGLhx3NoJ10RCsvg-B5xucI73InLEPNJg4B0yhKjYepSDWJK1QFTdSVSsVKQnSddEKIgjI08xGQogbjQAKloOjcCgB1zSEQQIigIbTS6rgPTAdcW2JCAOzYloTE8YQAHJfT-HA0lwPafXDJypCUq0FC68i7CMkQ7DImIQrsIA)

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will take the approach mentioned but it does leave me worried that stuff can break like this :S